# Extracting the first element of the first sublist of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
data = {{0.0156863, 0.0156863, 0.0156863}, {0.01568343, 0.01568343, 0.01568343}}
```

and my strategy is this.

```
Take[Take[{data, 1], 1]
```

but an answer is

> `{{0.0156863, 0.0156863, 0.0156863}}`

I expected 0.0156863

Comment: Try `data[[1, 1]]`

Comment: Also, look up [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)  in the documetation

Comment: Not the nicest but also possible: `First[First[data]]`.